# Как в php хранить значение в памяти, видимое во всех скриптах?

Tags: php

Добрый день.

Как хранить в оперативной памяти какое-нибудь значение, например, количество подключений (людей/товара на складе), например, где при каждом подключение к значению будет прибавляться +1. При этом не используя сессии/файлы/БД. Хочется как-то хранить это значение с максимально быстрым доступом.

Спасибо.

Comment: memcached?

Answer (score 1):

В простейшем варианте `Memcached` или `Redis` позволяют решить интересующую вас задачу. Причем весьма эффективно.

Comment: Вам поможет NoSQL:

[memcache][1] - для хранения в памяти  
[redis][2] - для хранения в памяти и на жестком диске


  [1]: http://php.net/manual/ru/book.memcache.php
  [2]: http://redis.io/

Comment: @VasyOk 
Redis is an open source, BSD licensed, advanced key-value cache and store.

-------
И данные он держит в памяти, а на диск сораняет по команде и настройкам конфига.